# Is the display width actually working in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

> This optional display width may be
>   used by applications to display
>   integer values having a width less
>   than the width specified for the
>   column by left-padding them with
>   spaces.

Does the display width actually work in MySQL?

```
`type` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,

mysql> select length(type) from wp_orders;
+--------------+
| length(type) |
+--------------+
|            1 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It seems to me that `length(type)` should be at least `2` if it's working correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify zerofill when using an optional display width. Personally i would do all my formatting in my application code.

```
drop table if exists foo;
create table foo
(
area_code smallint(4) unsigned zerofill not null default 0
)
engine=innodb;

insert into foo (area_code) values (781),(727);

select * from foo;
+-----------+
| area_code |
+-----------+
|      0781 |
|      0727 |
+-----------+
```